Can I marry a Christian woman who doesn't practise her religion?
I'm interested in marriage with a Christian woman who was baptized as a Catholic at birth and lives in a Christian nation in a conservative/ religious region. She's officially registered as a member of the Church in this country and she and her parents pay the Church tax. However, they do not go to Church on Sundays and she is not fully convinced about the existence of a God. Besides this, she is chaste and has had no previous sexual partners. Would this marriage be permissible for me?
